# Print data in a listview to look like an invoice

Tags: c#, listview, printing

I have created a simple POS system and want to print the data in a listview consisting of products prices and quantity.

I wish to add the logo of the company at the very top and then the data in the columns that follow.

Comment: do you want to print using crystal report or directly from the form?

Comment: i basically want to create an invoice from the data in the listview and a textbook that gets the grandtotal. so as long as all these data can be accessed and printed then i do not mind printing it from crystal report or from the form. thnaks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might want to take a look at http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **[PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** of .NET, like this:

```
   try {
        // If you want a preview use the PrintPreviewDialog
        PrintPreviewDialog preview = new PrintPreviewDialog();

        PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
        document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage);

        preview.Document = document;
        // Then show the dialog window.
        preview.Show();

        // Otherwise, just call the document.Print();

   } catch {
       throw;

   }
```

And have your printpage event like this, with this you can get the values from your listview control and format the layout as necessary to look much like an invoice:

```
    protected void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev) {
        Font printFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
        ev.Graphics.DrawString("Sample String", printFont, Brushes.Black, ev.MarginBounds.Left, ev.MarginBounds.Top, new StringFormat());
    }
```

This will directly print the text you want, but if you want to select the printer first, you may want to use the **[PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx)** of .NET.

Comment: ev.Graphics.DrawString("Sample String", printFont, Brushes.Black, ev.MarginBounds.Top, new StringFormat()); few questions @peyton crow 1. Just to clarify, this code above will print 1 line of text, which in this case I presume is Sample String? 2. so to access the items in my listview what i need is to loop through all the items and replace "Sample String" as the argument? do you have a link to show what the arguments of the DrawString method? Cheers. And thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: 1 & 2: Yes, this is correct.
The link is actually in my post.